# Why is theme undefined in styled component props?

Tags: styled-components

Here I access theme by passing a callback function to the styled tag. I guess styled calls this callback function with the props as first argument. This works well.

```
export default function SectionHeading(props: SectionHeadingProps) {
    const Heading = styled.h2`
        ${props => props.theme.green && `
            color: green;
        `}
    `;

    return (
        <Heading>{propss.children}</Heading>
    );
}
```

In this example I pass an expression that contains the props the component has received. Here, theme is undefined.

```
export default function SectionHeading(props: SectionHeadingProps) {
    const Heading = styled.h2`
        ${props.theme.green && `
            color: green;
        `}
    `;

    return (
        <Heading>{props.children}</Heading>
    );
}
```

Why is theme undefined in the second example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is that these are different "props" and they are evaluated in different times, in the first example, the props are the props passed to the styled component, augmented with theme (provided you used `<ThemeProvider .../>`. In the second example, it is the props passed to your component.

The injection of the theme is done by styled-component library and only to styled components. Your component doesn't get it (because it is not a styled component).

Btw, your code has redundant nesting and creates a styled component each time it is invoked.

The way to do it is to simply define:

```
const SectionHeading = styled.div`
  ${props => (props.theme && props.theme.green && {color: 'green'})};
`;
```

and then:

```
export default SectionHeading;
```

Note that your sample code has a typo in the first part, you wrote `{propss.children}` (an extra 's').